# Parse JSON Data from a String variable and convert it to objects in a $scope.variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a string variable containg JSON data as below.

`var jsonstring = [{"latitude":"51.5263","longitude":"-0.120285","altitude":"","device":"123","rating":"5","region":"Europe","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 1","application":"Phone","age":"< 1 Year"},
{"latitude":"27.58","longitude":"23.43","altitude":"","device":"Asc 140","rating":"4","region":"Africa","customer":"","time":"< 1 Week","error":"Error 1","application":"PCB","age":"1-3 Years"},
{"latitude":"39.55","longitude":"116.25","altitude":"","device":"CVB","rating":"4","region":"China","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 2","application":"Sorting","age":"3-5 Years"}]`

I want to get this string and convert it to an array of objects (*which would be a $scope.variable*) so that i can be able to access each object individually. 
I tried to use the *JSON.parse()* but it gets the entire string into one object instead of multiple objects.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: This is `array-of-objects`..I doubt you will get only _one_ object

Comment: `JSON.parse()` should give you an array of objects.

Comment: var arr = jQuery.parseJSON("${jsonData.encodeAsJavaScript()}");

Comment: JSON.parse() worked just fine for me, and returned three objects.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/proe80pj/ JSON.parse() works fine

Comment: @SatejS, 
It throws this error.
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: @shoghi07, the whole var json=.... itself results in three objects for me.Additionally, the link posted above works too.Is there any other possible cause for it?

Comment: @SatejS, can you share the code that you tried where 3 objects were returned ?

Comment: @shoghi07, here you go https://jsfiddle.net/proe80pj/1/. it's virtually the link by benederr.

Answer (score 0):

You've to parse the entire string with `JSON.parse`.

Each object in the array can then be reached like any other array, e.g. `myArray[index]`, `myArray.map()` / `myArray.forEach()` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonstring = '[{"latitude":"51.5263","longitude":"-0.120285","altitude":"","device":"123","rating":"5","region":"Europe","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 1","application":"Phone","age":"< 1 Year"}, {"latitude":"27.58","longitude":"23.43","altitude":"","device":"Asc 140","rating":"4","region":"Africa","customer":"","time":"< 1 Week","error":"Error 1","application":"PCB","age":"1-3 Years"}, {"latitude":"39.55","longitude":"116.25","altitude":"","device":"CVB","rating":"4","region":"China","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 2","application":"Sorting","age":"3-5 Years"}]';
$scope.variable = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

Comment: I tried using that but throws this error
Unexpected token u

This is the code that I tried to run.
`$scope.variable = []; 
 $scope.variable = $.parseJSON(jsonstring);`

Comment: Your're right: the data you have is a JSON **string**, so - as you correcly already did - you name it `jsonstring`. But, then, you have to enclose your array of objects in single quotes, since `JSON.parse()` expects a string...

Comment: This is what I tried to do.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on1pqbyp/3/)

The objects are not stored in the `$scope.variable` when I check in the console. It shows this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: You can't do `var data = "'" + jsontring + "'";`

Answer (score 0):

[{"latitude":"51.5263","longitude":"-0.120285","altitude":"","device":"123","rating":"5","region":"Europe","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 1","application":"Phone","age":"< 1 Year"},
{"latitude":"27.58","longitude":"23.43","altitude":"","device":"Asc 140","rating":"4","region":"Africa","customer":"","time":"< 1 Week","error":"Error 1","application":"PCB","age":"1-3 Years"},
{"latitude":"39.55","longitude":"116.25","altitude":"","device":"CVB","rating":"4","region":"China","customer":"","time":"1-2 Weeks","error":"Error 2","application":"Sorting","age":"3-5 Years"}]

This is an array object.It's not a string object.

You can try again like this:

var jsonString = "[]";
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);

Comment: This is what I tried.

`var jsonstring = [...] //The JSON String
 var json = JSON.parse(jsonstring);`

It throws this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Comment: The variable jsonstring is an array object.so you do not need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method parses a **string** as JSON.
Code in your question, shows that you are trying to parse a JS object and not a string.

In the following example, you get an error if you try to parse a JS object.

```
var jsonstring = [{},{}];
JSON.parse(jsonstring); // ERROR Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

The following works instead (please note jsonstring is a string and not an object here):

```
var jsonstring = '[{},{}]';
JSON.parse(jsonstring); // OK
```

Comment: Ok I got what you answered above and tried doing this.

`var temp = " ' " + jsonstring + " ' "; 
        console.log("New JSON: ", JSON.parse(temp));`
It still does not work.

Trying the `console.log('temp');`` results into **'undefined'**

Comment: @shoghi07 please post a full example of what you are doing on jsfiddle so we can have a better look at it thank!

Comment: This is the link for the fiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on1pqbyp/1/)

It shows this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`

Comment: Looking at your original code var data = "'" + jsontring + "'"; it cannot work, as jsontring is already an object and wrapping around " won't make it a string.